# PHP: Get url of the parent page

Tags: php, url

I have a php page which generates image. I want to use this image in different page. While generating image, I want to take not of the page which is using this image. How can I get the URL of the page which is using this image?

xyz.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="my-php-to-generate-image.php" />
    </body>
</html>
```

In the above example, how will "my-php-to-generate-image.php" know that the calling page is "xyz.html" without passing any extra parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]
```

But this is not reliable. Instead you can use like this:

```
my-php-to-generate-image.php?page=thisPage
```

and call using

```
$_REQUEST['page'];
```

Comment: Yes, this is the best way when I am using this image. I want to track which other websites are using it and I don't expect them to pass any parameters.

Comment: But in PHP `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` is the only way